# arduino serial and pySerial

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

I am playing with arduino. Inside the projects book it has a project for getting the temperature from a temperature sensor. I hooked as it says and wrote the following simple code

```c
const int sensorPin = A0;
void loop(){
    int sensorVal = analogRead(sensorPin);
    float voltage = (sensorVal / 1024.0)* 5.0;
    float temperature = (voltage - .5) * 100;
    Serial.println(temperature);
}
```

to print the temperature in the serial monitor. I used pySerial to get the temp from the arduino like this

```
try:
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
except serial.SerialException as se:
    print se
    exit()

while True:
    temperature = ser.readline()
    print "Temp from arduino", temperature
    try:
        temperature = float(temperature)
        print "FLoat temperature", temperature
    except ValueError as ve:
        print ve
        continue
```

But the problem is that while the Serial monitor from the arduino ide shows the temperature normally (22.3 e.g) a normal float number that is python has the number divided by 10

```
Temp from arduino 2.27
FLoat temperature 2.27
```

How can I deal with that?

Comment: Your outputs are identical? Also, you would want to do `float()` much ealier, beacause after recieving the data.. You've already ruined it by not treating it as a `float()` from the start. For instance, you can't do `x = 10.15; x = int(x); x = float(x);` because it will end up `10` even tho you try to convert it back. Not that this will help but do `temperature = float(ser.readline()` instead.

Comment: It's strange to have a difference between the output in the serial monitor and in the input pySerial. I see no reason for that - both of them show text coming from the serial interface.  I have two questions and one suggestion. Why don't you divide by 1023 instead of 1024? Why is this `- .5`? Try to print the `voltage` value to the serial to see the results.

Comment: @Torxed ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 22.73.24 this is what I get for float(ser.readline()) Its like its reading a line and something from the following line...Must I sync arduino Serial.println() and python's serial.readline()?

Comment: @Torxed I don't think something is ruined... the first time `temperature` is a string and this is a good idea to print in for debugging before converting it to float. Really it's a better practice to use different variables for that...

Comment: @AndreiBoyanov As i can tell its 10 bit number coming from the analogRead(). Just coppied the example from book for now.

Comment: 10 bit number means from 0 to 1023, right?

Comment: `invalid literal for float(): 22.73.24` tells me that something other was written by the Arduino to the serial interface. But in this case the output of your program would by `Temp from arduino 2.273.24`...

Comment: I changed the casting using different variables one for serial output(string) and one for temperature(float). Now i get mixxed results. Some are temperatures like normal ones some like 0.5 or 5..

Comment: Could it be because I was having the Ide monitor openned up at the same time with python script running?

Answer (score 0):

It seams that something else except the temperature is printed to the serial interface by your Arduino. Try to prefix the temperature with some tag and to parse it in the python side:

```
Serail.print('Temp:')
Serial.println(temperature);
```

And in the client:

```
input = ser.readline()
print "Input from arduino", input
try:
    if input.startswith('Temp:')
    temperature = float(input[len('Temp'):])
        print "Float temperature", temperature
```